# Why does my newly complied and installed linux kernel appear in 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I compiled another kernel and installed it.
then I upgraded grub.
But what is confusing me is that after I reboot the PC and about to choose which kernel to boot, I found the newly installed kernel didn't appear in the main menu, but in the 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'.
why dose this happens and what to do to move it to the main menu.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

### Submenu Display

> The Grub2 menu will look unchanged until more than one kernel is available for selection. When more than one kernel is available, Grub2 will automatically add a submenu.
>
> 1. The latest kernel is displayed on the main menu. Additional (older) kernels are displayed in the submenu.
> 2. The submenu is a special menuentry with a title of "Previous Linux versions".
>      **In GRUB 2.0 (Ubuntu 12.10, Quantal Quetzel and later) the submenu title is "Advanced options ..."**
> 3. Users access additional kernels by highlighting the "Previous Linux versions" menuentry and pressing the ENTER key.
>
>    Once the submenu is selected additional kernels will be displayed on a secondary menu.
> 4. **When a newer kernel is installed, the previous kernel on the main menu will be moved to the submenu.**
> 5. The submenu feature is only created by default on the currently running Linux system.

<sub>[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus)</sub>